# default_controller route does not work with a function not_found in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been working with codeigniter for a long time. I have set my default controller to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
```

everything is fine, except I have created a function in `main.php` controller file that redirects to 404 Not Found page.

This is my code in main.php:

```
function not_found()
{
    $data['page_Title'] = '404 Error!';
    $data['page_Description'] = 'Description';
    $data['page_Keywords'] = 'Keywords';
$data['main_content'] = 'not_found';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data); 
}
```

Then when I want to load `example.com/not_found/` it redirects me to the codeigniter's default not found page and says:

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

but, there is no problem requesting the page like:

```
example.com/main/not_found/
```

Do I have to set another route like:

```
$route['not_found'] = "main/not_found";
```

?! but this is not a good way I think!

Comment: Yes, you have to setup that route to map the "not_found" method to the main.php controller else it'll throw the default CI 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

The url format of CI describes :

```
domain.com/controller/method
```

And not:

```
domain.com/method
```

If you have a `index function` in your controller then that function will be called like this:

```
domain.com
```

Comment: so I have to set another route?!

Comment: I you want to chnage the `404 error` then change this line in your application/config/routes.php : `$route['404_override'] = 'main/not_found';`

Comment: no of course I don't want to do it because routing 404_override is both for admin section and user side. but my templates differs in them! But I got what to do! thanks

Answer (score 1):

**example.com/not_found/** mean, codeIgniter will find **controllers/not_found.php** and execute **function index()**

You have to create **controllers/not_found.php**